# Removing NIL's from a list LISP

Tags: list, lisp, null

Simple question.

Say I have a bunch of NIL's in my list q . Is there a simple way to remove the NILs and just keep the numbers?. eval doesn't seem to work here.

```
(NIL 1 NIL 2 NIL 3 NIL 4)
```

I need `(1 2 3 4)`

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a filter function.  Which Lisp dialect (Scheme, Common Lisp, etc.) are you using?

Comment: Common Lisp. It makes sense for there to be a built in function that ignores NILs..

Comment: @JohnPick nailed it, check out his answer!

Comment: if this is homework, tag it as such

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Common Lisp, instead of remove-if you can use remove:

```
(remove nil '(nil 1 nil 2 nil 3 nil 4))
```

Answer (score 11):

In common lisp and perhaps other dialects:

```
(remove-if #'null '(NIL 1 NIL 2 NIL 3 NIL 4))
```

Comment: User "Spec" has a more straightforward answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Scheme, this will work nicely:

```
(define lst '(NIL 1 NIL 2 NIL 3 NIL 4))

(filter (lambda (x) (not (equal? x 'NIL)))
        lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

As I noted in my comment above, I'm not sure which Lisp dialect you are using, but your problem fits exactly into the mold of a filter function (Python has good documentation for its filter [here](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter)).  A Scheme implementation taken from SICP is

```
(define (filter predicate sequence)
  (cond ((null? sequence) nil)
        ((predicate (car sequence))
         (cons (car sequence)
               (filter predicate (cdr sequence))))
        (else (filter predicate (cdr sequence)))))
```

assuming of course that your Lisp interpreter doesn't have a built-in filter function, as I suspect it does.  You can then keep only the numbers from your list `l` by calling

```
(filter number? l)
```

Answer (score 0):

`(remove-if-not #'identity list)`