# LISP disposing of pesky NILs

Tags: lisp, null

I have the following filter function that filters out a list, x, that doesn't satisfy the function f.

For example, I call `(filter 'evenp '(0 1 2 3))` and get back `(NIL 1 NIL 3)`. But this is exactly my problem. How do I make it so that I just get back `(1 3)` ?

```
(defun filter (f x)
    (setq h (mapcar #'(lambda (x1)
                        (funcall f x1))
                    x))
    (mapcar #'(lambda (a b)
                (cond ((null a) b)))
            h x))
```

i.e. the problem is right here: `(lambda (a b) (cond ( (null a) b)  )  )` In my `cond` I don't have a `t` , or else statement, so shouldn't it just stop right there and not return `nil` ? How do I make it "return" nothing, not even `nil`, if the `(cond ( (null a) b) )` isn't satisfied?

Much appreciated. :)

Comment: `h` is an undefined variable. You need to define it. Also, is this homework?

Comment: Suspect `h` is meant to be inside a `let`; it looks the poster is trying to use it as intermediate storage, and then filter the nulls out from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355918/removing-nils-from-a-list-lisp) it would be:

```
(remove-if #'evenp '(0 1 2 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the other questions raised by this post, I'll say that `mapcar` will always return something for each thing it's mapping over, so you can't use another `mapcar` to clean up the NILs there.  This is what `mapcar` does -- it walks over the item (or items, if mapping on multiple lists, as your second attempted `mapcar` does) and collects the result of calling some function on those arguments.

Instead, in this situation, if you had to use mapcar for some reason, and didn't want the NILs, you could use the `remove` function, i.e. `(remove nil (mapcar ...))`

Since @stark's answer is posted above, I'll say that the `remove-if` function there is essentially what you're trying to implement here.  (That's where the question of whether or not this is for homework becomes most relevant.)

Answer (score 1):

To answer the more general question of how to splice an arbitrary number of items (including none at all) into the result, [`mapcan`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm#mapcan) (which is semantically `mapcar` + `append`) is useful for that:

```
(defun filter (f xs)
  (mapcan (lambda (x)
            (if (funcall f x)
                (list x)
                nil))
          xs))
```

`mapcan` is also useful when you want to map an item to multiple results:

```
(defun multi-numbers (xs)
  (mapcan (lambda (x) (list x (+ x x) (* x x))) xs))

(multi-numbers (list 1 2 3))
;=> (1 2 1 2 4 4 3 6 9)
```